# Infragistics UltraToolbar NonInheritedTools

Tags: infragistics

sorry if this topic already was solved.. 
but I really have doubts about certain infragistics property.. 
the "**NonInheritedTools**" and its documentation is very very poor.
what is it for? can I ignore it?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've used Infragistics controls for over 10 years for WinForms, WPF, and asp.net projects and have never found the need for it in any of my WinForm tool bars coding. As best as I can tell, it seems to be for internal Infragistics use only. Unless you can find a specific need, I would ignore it, but that is just my opinion from my experience. Unless you have a specific programming question that is as much as I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

The comments on the NonInheritedTools class (not property) says the following:

"For Infragistics internal use. Collection for iterating the non-inherited tools in a tools collection."

Comment: yes, I saw that.. It seems not useful for own purposes.. thanks